# Error while doing filter in AWS Glue piepline

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue

I am running a query in AWS GLUE and loading the output into 4 different files using FILTER option as given below:

```
df = glueContext.read.format("jdbc").option("driver", jdbc_driver_name).option("url", db_url).option("query", query).option("user", db_username).option("password", db_password).load()
filtered_df0 = df.filter("ORDR_DOC_TYPE='0005'")
filtered_df1 = df.filter("ORDR_DOC_TYPE='0001'")
filtered_df2 = df.filter("ORDR_DOC_TYPE='0003'")
filtered_df3 = df.filter("(ORDR_STTS_CD)='9000' AND (LN_ITEM_REL_QTY)>'0.00' AND (col1)>=(col2)")
```

I am getting the data into 4 different files using above 4 filters. But the 4th filter condition:

```
(col1) >= (col2)
```

is causing some issue. There is no failure as such, but I am getting count mismatch. Then I tried to modify that filer as below:

```
filtered_df3 = Filter.apply(frame = df, f = lambda x: x["col1"]>=x["col2"])
```

When I run this, GLUE job is failing due to below error:

```
TypeError: DataFrame.filter() takes 2 positional arguments but 6 were given
```

Tried my best to fix it. But no luck.
Can someone please help me to fix it??`help`

Comment: Are any of these columns partitions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the pyspark column function in your filter statement.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

filtered_df3 = df.filter((col(ORDR_STTS_CD)== "9000") &
                           (col(LN_ITEM_REL_QTY) > 0.00) &
                           (col(col1) >= col(col2)))
```

Another thought is ensuring that the columns you are using with the greater than operator (`>`) are numbers. If they are not numbers, it could be returning some funny results.

`filter.apply` is not an option for the pyspark `filter` command

More details on pyspark `filter`: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.filter.html